# Travel between terminals at Charles de Gaulle before exiting the airport?

Tags: transportation, cdg

can I go from terminal 2E to Terminal 1 to meet up with the rest of my party so we can leave the airport together? and how long will it take?  should I use the CDGVAL?

Comment: What exactly does "exiting the airport" mean for you here? If you're traveling with checked baggage you'll need to pick it up at the terminal you arrive into, and then you're landside. Of course once you're landside nothing will stop you from going to the land side of a different terminal and meet the rest of the party, all while staying on land owned by the airport. But often people count it as "exiting the airport" whenevery they leave the sterile airside area ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a train connection (RER B) between the different terminals. Assuming you gathered everything, it should take you about 15min to find it and travel through. See [here](http://easycdg.com/ground-transportation/charles-de-gaulle-airport-cdg-to-paris-by-rer-train/) the links to CDG accomodations and below an image that sums it up.

[image]

Comment: can you please add some links about this connection?

Comment: I've made it myself this summer. There are two train stations: the first is for terminals 1 and 3, the second for terminal 2. I guess I can find links, if that is what you're asking for.

Comment: Yeah, it will be great to see some links, thank you !